# Función distinta cuando hago click en un div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Tengo el siguiente ejercicio de `jQuery`, he estado  buscando funciones y no he encontrado nada, el ejercicio es el siguiente.

Crea un `div` de `800x70` con `background` gris, que al hacer `click` se ponga `250x250` y al hacer `click` de nuevo, vuelva a su tamaño original.

Hasta ahora he conseguido que al hacer el primer `click` si que se cambie al tamaño pedido en el ejercicio (mediante cambio de clases en `CSS`) pero no consigo encontrar la forma de que cuando haga el segundo `click` me vuelva estar por defecto.

Comment: Muestra lo que has conseguido hasta ahora

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes poner y quitar la clase con los estilos que necesitas usando `toggleClass`, por ejemplo

```js
 $('#myDiv').on('click', function(e){
    $(this).toggleClass('mutedDiv');
  });
```

```css
#myDiv{
  width: 800px;
  height: 700px;
  background-color:gray;
}

.mutedDiv{
  width: 250px!important;
  height: 250px!important;    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Asi cada vez que le des click al div o contenedor que selecciones pondrá o quitara la clase respectivamente si ya la posee o no

Comment: cree una respuesta alterna a la tuya, si te parece, unifica las dos y borro la mia.

Comment: @CamiloBernal ya edite la respuesta, gracias por el aporte.

Comment: Listo, ya eliminé la mia. :P

Comment: Muchas gracias, ha servido a la perfección !

Comment: ¿Esta respuesta solucionó tu problema, @llucmatas ? Por favor no olvides marcarla como aceptada si tu problema fue resuelto. Puedes hacerlo marcando el ✓ en la parte izquierda de la respuesta (se pondrá verde, ganarás 2 puntos de reputación y podrías acceder a [nuevos privilegios](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)). ¡Mira [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) si tienes alguna duda!

Answer (score 1):

Cuando haga click, cambiale o añadele una nueva.

Luego a traves de jquery cuando haga click, comprueba si lleva una clase u otra y en funcion de la clase que lleve haces lo que tengas que hacer.

```
$( "#id_que_buscas" ).on( "click", function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass("pepito")){
     $(this).addClass("juanito");
  }else{
     $(this).removeClass("pepito");
  }
});
```